# JDK7 JVM different from JDK8

Tags: java, jvm

When I run this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] b = null;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        b = new byte[1024 * 1024];
}
```

with JVM options `-Xmx20m -Xms20m -Xmn1m  -XX:+PrintGCDetails` in JDK7,Console will print
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dLby.png). When I run with this JVM options in JDK8,it will print

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
GC triggered before VM initialization completed. Try increasing NewSize, current value 1536K.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: NewSize (1536k) is greater than the MaxNewSize (1024k). A new max generation size of 1536k will be used.
```

Why?

Comment: Because JDK8 **is** different from JDK7. Also, why are you setting your memory limits so low?

Comment: Because I tried to assign all newly created objects to the older generation.So I found that this code can't work in JAVA8.What caused the code to run on JAVA7 instead of running it in JAVA8?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 1):

The observed behaviour is related to some changes between Java 7 and Java 8.

`-Xmn1024k`

this option sets the `initial` and the `maximum` size of the heap for the young generation. It's a shorthand for `-XX:NewSize=1024k -XX:MaxNewSize=1024k`.

```
// same command in Java 7/8
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -Xmn2048k -version | grep NewSize
...
uintx MaxNewSize                               := 2097152
uintx NewSize                                  := 2097152
...
```

This behaviour seems to be not in line with the documentation.

[Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

> -Xmnsize or -XX:NewSize
>   Sets the size of the young generation (nursery).

[Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html)

> The -XX:NewSize option is equivalent to -Xmn.

Because `-XX:NewSize=2048k` would set in Java7/8 only the initial size and the maximum size is chosen by the JVM.

Hence if you specify `-Xmn1024k` it actually means you want to set

```
-XX:NewSize=1024k -XX:MaxNewSize=1024k
```

In Java 7 (tested with 1.7.0_40-b43) the minimal size (for initial and maximum) is `196608`. If you set the value to low. The start of the JVM fails with

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small new size specified
```

In Java 8 (tested with 1.8.0_74-b02) minimal size (for initial and maximum) is `1572864` (1536K).

Now why you get this `NewSize (1536k) is greater than the MaxNewSize (1024k)` with Java 8.

If you choose `NewSize` lower than the minimal size (1536K) it's adjusted silently to that minimal size.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:NewSize=1k -version | grep NewSize
...
uintx NewSize                                  := 1572864
...
```

If you choose `MaxNewSize` lower than `NewSize` `MaxNewSize` will be set silently to `NewSize`

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:NewSize=2048k -XX:MaxNewSize=1025k -version | \
    grep NewSize
...
uintx MaxNewSize                               := 2097152
uintx NewSize                                  := 2097152
...
```

If you choose `NewSize` and `MaxNewSize` lower than minimal size and `MaxNewSize` bigger than `NewSize`, both are set to the minimal size.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:NewSize=1024k -XX:MaxNewSize=1025k -version | \
    grep NewSize
...
uintx MaxNewSize                               := 1572864
uintx NewSize                                  := 1572864
...
```

this even works for a complete low value for `NewSize`

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:NewSize=1 -XX:MaxNewSize=1025k -version | \
    grep NewSize
...
uintx MaxNewSize                               := 1572864
uintx NewSize                                  := 1572864
...
```

But as soon you choose for `MaxNewSize` a value <s>lower than `1025k`</s> equal to `1024k` you get the error message you have discovered. Seems you found an edge case where a check is done before the adjustment.

```
java -XX:NewSize=1 -XX:MaxNewSize=1025k -version
java version "1.8.0_74"

java -XX:NewSize=1 -XX:MaxNewSize=1024k -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: NewSize (1536k) is greater than the \
MaxNewSize (1024k). A new max generation size of 1536k will be used.
```

That's explains why `java -Xmn1025k -version` runs fine where as `java -Xmn1024k -version` gives you the error message.

**edit** After some more testing. The error seems to be printed only in case `MaxNewSize` is equal to `1024k`. The next examples are working with the default size for `NewSize` and `MaxNewSize`.

```
java -XX:NewSize=1 -XX:MaxNewSize=1023k -version
java -XX:NewSize=1 -XX:MaxNewSize=1 -version
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message contains the reason.

> GC triggered before VM initialization completed.

It is unrelated to your code since VM initialization happens before `main` runs.